# SQL Server: by default how long connection stays open if I forget to close it

Tags: .net, sql-server

Suppose

```
SqlDataReader oDR = ...
...
oDR.Read()
...

forgot to close!
```

Question: for how long connection will stay open by default? Can I change this?

Comment: Please see my answer. I think it really answers your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Until the garbage collector cleans it up.

Which translates to: Some indeterminate period of time.

Which translates to: Don't do it, always close it when you're done with it.

Comment: not an answer. Reread the question: for how long connection will stay open by default? Can I change this?

Comment: @Downlalatech - an *indeterminate* amount of time - as Lasse says, it will get closed when the GC kicks in, the timing of that depends on other memory usage.

Comment: @Downlalatech I think it is an answer. `***Connection` class implements IDisposable, which will be triggered by GC if connection is not explicitly closed and goes out of scope. If connection object doesn't go out of scope it will never be closed.

Comment: IDisposable/Dispose will not be triggered by GC, but the connection object has a finalizer, which will. Typically they do the same, but let's be precise here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is a bit more complicated. In general, ADO.NET uses pooling. This way it boosts performance, by avoiding the need to open and close connections, which is kind of slow on both the client and server side.

As long as what happens with your connection it will be disposed when the GC collects it. Non-deterministic. You can't control it.

But disposing it's not the same as closing the connection, but making it available in the pool again.

You can control connection pooling in your connection string:
[Connection Pooling for the .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

This allows you to control the pool size, lifetime, etc.

In the C# code sie, the best practice for Disposable objects, like DB Connections, is to create it inside an `using` block, which will dispose your object, even in the case of an unhandled exception.